# JSF (and PrimeFaces) How to pass parameter to a method in ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, primefaces, managed-bean

I have an Employee object I am showing in inputtext.
For example, the firstname of the employee is shown in an inputtext. When the value of this firstname changes it calls a method. Before this is done I want to call a method which saves the ID of the employee in the managedbean so I know which employee needs to be changed.
How do I do this, I got this so far:

```
<h:outputText value="First name:"/>
<p:inplace id="firstname" editor="true">
     <p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="#{employeeController.saveName()}"/>
     <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{emp.firstName}"  
                  required="true" label="text"
                  valueChangeListener="#{employeeController.firstNameChanged}">
     <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{employeeController.onValueChangedStart}"/>
     </p:inputText>
</p:inplace>
```

I guess I should pass the ID with the onValueChangedStart or firstNameChanged method. How do I do this? Or is there a better way to do this? There is a getter for the emp. So #{emp}.id to get it.

Comment: Is this inside a datatable? The `#{emp}` isn't a property of `#{employeeController}` which is at first sight quite strange.

Comment: This is inside a datatable. So the answer you give was helpfull

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you're indeed inside a repeating component where `#{emp}` is been exposed by its `var` attribute, you could just grab it from the EL scope inside the value change listener as follows:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Employee employee = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{emp}", Employee.class);
Long id = employee.getId();
// ...
```

Alternatively, if you wrap the `value` of the `<h:dataTable>` inside a `DataModel<Employee>`, then you can obtain the current row as follows:

```
Employee employee = model.getRowData();
Long id = employee.getId();
// ...
```

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's unnecessary to have two listener methods for the value change. Note that the `valueChangeListener` gives you the opportunity to get both the old and new value by the event and the `p:ajax listener` not, the new value is already been set as model value at that point. If you need both the old and new value, remove the `listener` attribute of `<p:ajax>`. The `event="valueChange"` is by the way the default event already, so just remove it as well.

Comment: Do you know if it's also possible to render the inplace again? It still shows the old value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I put a javascript with alert to test if it renders, it does. But it looks like it renders it before it does the value change. I use <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="@this"/> When I refresh the page it does have the correct value.

Comment: Please ask a new question. It's unrelated to the initial question.

Comment: Got it solved adding a p:ajax event="save" update="@this". Added this beneath the other p:ajax line.

Comment: I have adapted this suggestion by BalusC to use an "elegant hack" to exploit the id of the p:inplace to propagate (to a save event listener) a translated form of the EL expression for an entity whose value is being edited by inplace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405613/jsf-primefaces-pinplace-how-to-more-elegantly-propagate-the-el-expression-for

Comment: Imagine it inside ui:repeat, and we want to get row data in listener. But UIRepeat has private access to getDataModel(). Is there a way to get row data without evaluationg expression "#{emp}"?

Answer (score 5):

Using primefaces ajax you can retrieve the value of an input in java doing:

```
public void onValueChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    Employee employee = (Employee)((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue();
    //...
}

<h:selectOneMenu required="true"
    value="#{empl}" converter="#{bean.employeeConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.employees}" var="varEmployee" 
        itemLabel="#{varEmployee}" itemValue="#{varEmployee}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onValueChanged}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Instead of casting to employee you cast to String since your value is a String, or use the employee Object and use a Converter or its toString() method.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="#{employeeController.saveName(emp.id)}"/>
```