# JSF composite component backing bean EL expression as default of required attribute failing, methods not known

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, default, composite-component

I have a JSF composite component util_primefaces:inplace_name that requires a "manager" backing bean that performs persistence updates when the 'name' field of an entity is edited (using p:inplace):

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute name="manager" type="com.example.web.AbstractManager" required="false" default="#{blockManager}"/>
  <cc:attribute name="element" type="com.example.entity.Element" required="true"/>
  <cc:attribute name="elid" required="true"/>
  <cc:attribute name="update" required="false" default="@parent"/>
 ..
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
 ..
 <p:inplace id="#{cc.attrs.elid}" editor="true" emptyLabel="UNDEF" >
  <p:ajax 
   event="save" 
   listener="#{cc.attrs.manager.onInplaceNameSaveEvent}"
   process="@this #{cc.attrs.elid}-name"
   update="#{cc.attrs.update}"
  />
 <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.elid}-name" value="#{cc.attrs.element.name}"/>
 ..
```

Where for example @ViewScoped @ManagedBean BlockManager ultimately extends an AbstractManager, which has a listener method:

```
public void onInplaceNameSaveEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent ae).
```

[ASIDE: the reason for the unusual "elid" attribute is described here, it plays no further role in this question: [Primefaces p:inplace: How to more elegantly propagate the EL expression for entity to merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405613/jsf-primefaces-pinplace-how-to-more-elegantly-propagate-the-el-expression-for) ]

When I invoke the composite component passing in an explicit #{blockManager} (or other subclass of AbstractManager) it works fine:

```
<util_primefaces:inplace_name 
 element="#{tenancy}" 
 elid="tenancy"
 manager="#{blockManager}"
/>
```

But if I don't pass in the #{blockManager}, on performing the inplace edit and save I get an error that the method onInplaceNameSaveEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent) is not known:

```
<util_primefaces:inplace_name 
 element="#{tenancy}" 
 elid="tenancy"
/>
```

The error is:

```
WARNING: Method not found: com.example.web.BlockManager@71396a88.onInplaceNameSaveEvent(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.example.web.BlockManager@71396a88.onInplaceNameSaveEvent(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:155)
```

Q: Why is the backing bean not taken correctly using default="#{blockManager}" in the composite component attribute ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation for the tag `cc:attribute`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/composite/attribute.html), the value for `default` must evaluate to a `java.lang.String`.

That's why the `#{blockManager}` expression is not working as you are expecting, you only can set defaults for `String` attributes.

To see what happens, you can test registering the following function in a taglib ([like showed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript)):

```
public static String typeOf(Object o) {
    return o == null ? null : o.getClass().toString();
}
```

and use it in a composite component like this:

```
<ui:composition>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="param" type="java.lang.Integer" required="true"
            default="1" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:outputText value="#{fnc:typeOf(cc.attrs.param)}" />
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

Now, if you use the component without specifying `param`, like this:

```
<my:comp />
```

... it will output `class java.lang.String`, because it uses the result of the ValueExpression for the *default* attribute, which is the String `"1"`.

And when you specify param:

```
<my:comp param="1" />
```

... it outputs `class java.lang.Integer`, cause now it's the value resulting from coercing to the type specified for the `cc:attribute`.

Comment: many thanks. BTW I tried a couple of related experiments with curious results, for example if define an attribute name="testInteger" type="java.lang.Integer" default="1a" (note the deliberate alpha character in the default String) and h:outputText value=#{cc.attrs.testInteger}" it outputs ok as **1a** (not an Integer) when i invoke component without an explicit testInteger, however if I invoke the composite component with testInteger="1b" it fails as expected with a NumberFormatException.

Comment: interesting... going to do some tests of my own too! thanks! :)