# EL in composite component on Mojarra

Tags: jsf, composite-component, mojarra

help me with problem.

I use Mojarra 2.1.16 and Tomcat 7.

I have composite component:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" default="#{modelsBean.allModels}"
                         type="java.util.List" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="model" >
        #{model.name}
    </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

If I use it, then I have next error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/panels/modelsView.xhtml
#{model.name}: Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String
```

If I change

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="model">
```

to

```
<ui:repeat value="#{modelsBean.allModels}" var="model">
```

then all work ok.

How to fix then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign a value expression as `default` value. See here for a more detailed explanation: [JSF composite component backing bean EL expression as default of required attribute failing, methods not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596470/jsf-composite-component-backing-bean-el-expression-as-default-of-required-attrib)

Comment: But, as you can see, the attribute type is described as a list:
    <composite:attribute name="value"
    default="#{modelsBean.allModels}"
    type="java.util.List" />
I have problem with elements of this list.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, `default` seems to work only with values that are strings or primitives. See the answer of the link above for more. Just don't use `default` and set the value where you use your component. `<mytags:component value="#{modelsBean.allModels}">`